# Samsung recovery solution 5 - Restore backup to blank hard disk

Tags: windows-7, boot, backup, hard-drive-recovery

Has anyone had any success with restoring a Samsung (Win 7) that uses the **Samsung Recovery Solution 5** onto a new (thus blank) hard disk?

I've taken the complete backup through the POST <kbd>F4</kbd> functionality which is now saved to a USB hard disk. I've checked the USB and there are a number or 4GB files, but nothing that jumps out as being boot files.

Call me daft, but, how the devil is one supposed to get said backup onto a blank hard disk if the Samsung Recovery Solution 5 isn't already installed on the machine (i.e. already requiring Windows to be installed)!

Is there a bootable disk I've forgotten to make (or, shall I say, that the Samsung Recovery Solution software has neglected to mention is needed)?

I have still got the original hard disk but it is slowly failing and I would like to be able to get the backup onto a new disk ASAP but if I need to make a bootable disk in some special manner then I simply cannot find this anywhere... the Samsung support website seems to only show instructions on how to restore if you're simply restoring from the same, original hard disk (which I'm not).

I *could* CloneZilla or FOG the disk but the disk is showing some bad sectors which `chkdsk` has already identified and moved to the bad sector files so I'd rather start from scratch.

Comment: I don't know where else to post this since you deleted your comments that somebody foudn useful, but did you answer this guy's question http://superuser.com/questions/939951/is-the-need-for-a-text-editor-in-an-os-for-humans-or-the-system  he acknowledged that you answered it , he liked your answer, and then you deleted your answer?